# Access children of react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, high-order-component

Imagine having React component

```
function List() {
   return (<ul>
             <li>1</li>
             <li>2</li>
           </ul>
    );
}
```

I would like to create high-order component which modifies, for example, styles of all `li` node.

```
function makeRed(component) {
    return function(props) {
         const element = React.createElement(component, props);

         return React.cloneElement(
            element,
            element.props,
            React.Children.map(
                element.props.children,
                ch => React.cloneElement(ch, { 
                        ...ch.props, 
                        style: {
                           backgroundColor: "red"
                        }
                    },                    
                    ch.props.children
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

But. This doesn't work. Children are empty.

Interesting that this works if I create component directly, like

```
...    
const element = <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>;
...
```

Question: how to access a children and grandchildren of any React element?

Comment: This very much seems like an anti-pattern in React. Why not instead create a `List` component that can accept styles as a prop, and a higher-order component that passes said prop to them?

Comment: can you give a more practical example of what you want to do? your example is much more easily achieved with plain old css

Comment: I need this to add "sortable (draggable)" behavior to any element with children with HOC. I know this is not a pure react way for normal components but that's just the simplest example illustrates problem.

Comment: @STO this can be done as Hamms already said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern, as @hamms has pointed out. There are [better ways to implement themes in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) using plain old CSS.

Said that, here's a hack to a working example of your use case - https://codesandbox.io/s/ymqwyww22z.

Basically, here's what I have done:

1. Make `List` a class based component. It's not too much trouble to wrap a functional component into one.

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";

   export default class List extends Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <ul>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
         </ul>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Implement `render` in the dynamic class `Red<Component>` to first fetch the element-tree returned from the base Component's render and then edit it.

   ```
   import React from "react";

   export default function makeRed(Component) {
     return class RedComponent extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         RedComponent.displayName = `Red${Component.name}`;
       }

       render() {
         let componentElement = super.render();
         let { children, ...rest } = componentElement.props;
         children = React.Children.map(children, child => {
           return React.cloneElement(child, {
             ...child.props,
             style: {
               backgroundColor: "red"
             }
           });
         });
         return React.cloneElement(componentElement, rest, ...children);
       }
     };
   }
   ```

#### How's this different from the `createElement` version of `makeRed`?

As `makeRed` returns a HOC, when you use it in your `App` component, you don't assign props to it. Something like this...

```
function App() {
  return <RedList />; // no props!
}
```

So inside the dynamic component function, where you use `createElement` to create a new instance, `component.props` don't carry any children. Since `List` creates its own children, you need to grab those and modify them, instead of reading children from `props`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, marked as accepted. So children becomes available only for inheriting components? If I call `render()` directly or call a functional component, would it be the same?

Comment: With a functional component, you can directly call it to get the element tree, instead of `super.render`. You will need to make changes to the hoc to not extend the class in case Component is a function.