# Parent component returns children's divs one by one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-state

Components `A` and `B` return array of divs (which are updated based on global state changes) like so:

```
// code above

return(
  <>{divArray}</>
)
```

Component `C` imports both components and returns them in a div:

```
// code above
return(
  <div className='CC'>
    <A/>
    <B/>
  </div>
)
```

In usual render, array of component `A` will show above array of component `B`.
Is it possible to force div `'CC'` to show elements of both arrays one by one, i.e., element of array `A`, element of array `B`, element of array `A`, and so on?

Can I somehow call `.map` on imported components in return statement of `C`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access children of react element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776533/access-children-of-react-element)

Comment: Well you could do this one of two ways .. If the index count is the same .. You can simply `map()` the first array and use the `key` to call that `index` in the second array within the loop.  Or you can `useEffect` with both arrays passed in and create a single component with all the `divs` that way.

Comment: @PeterB this is too complicated, there should be something easier...

Comment: I'd say there isn't an easier way. React isn't made for such trickery. Components are meant to render into smaller / lower level components, which may or may not render another layer of children according to the same principle. And you normally don't need to see that from the outside. What I would do if I had this need is to dismantle A and B and create functions instead that just retun the arrays that you want. There is no need for everything to be a JSX component.

Comment: yeah, that's what I have now, I thought I could make it more sophisticated but can't find it... Will just use useEffects and handle these arrays inside one component, it's much easier... Thanks @PeterB !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const C = () => {
  const arrayA = <A/>.type().props.children
  const arrayB = <B/>.type().props.children
   
  return (
    <div className='CC'>
      {
        getAlternatingArray(arrayA, arrayB)
      }
    </div>  
  )
}

const getAlternatingArray = (arrayA, arrayB) => {
    let indexA = 0
    let indexB = 0
    const result = []
    while(indexA < arrayA.length && indexB < arrayB.length) {
      result.push(arrayA[indexA++]);
      result.push(arrayB[indexB++]);
    }
    while(indexA < arrayA.length) {
      result.push(arrayA[indexA++]);
    }
    while(indexB < arrayB.length) {
      result.push(arrayB[indexB++]);
    }
  return result
}
```

Comment: if this works you're a genuis, will test soon.

Comment: It works, here you have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/nicofetter/pen/PoxdmqQ)

Anyway Im not a genius haha

Comment: I'm wondering why you use `.map()` because it works even without the .map() and *without* it, things like `style` and `className` that may be on the `<div>`-s are preserved. WIth the .map() as it is (doing createElement), those props get lost, extra code would need to be added to put it all back in.

Comment: You are right @peter, edited the answer, no need to map thru them.